# Custom picker dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm new to Android. I have a default spinner in my app. I want to change the design of the spinner. When the spinner is clicked, picker dialog should appear on the screen, displaying scrollable list. I don't know how to implement the code to meet my requirements.

[image]

I have read these articles: [(1)](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) [(2)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog)

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look to the official guide for Dialogs usage in Android:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

And more specifically for pickers : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

For a number picker if your target is > to API 11: you can use the existing Android widget `NumberPicker`-> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html
Use this widget in a custom dialog box and it's done.

Comment: I've seen those links without any help.

Comment: So what is your problem exactly? Everything is explained with examples of implementations.

Comment: OK, I got the answer. But is there a template for [this](http://developer.android.com/design/media/picker_space.png) type of dialog?

Comment: Edited my answer, hope this correspond to your needs.